# Copying to clipboard with clipboard=unnamed set

Tags: cut-copy-paste

In the `~/.vimrc` the clipboard has been enabled:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

But after hitting `v` for Visual

[image]

and then hitting `y` (yank)  then `escape` there is no contents in the clipboard.

[image]
https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

What else needs to be done?

Comment: Are you really pressing `Esc` before `y`? Because that wil cancel the visual mode selection.

Comment: Nice observation: I corrected the post and included screenshot of `yanked` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `clipboard=unnamed` requires that your copy of Vim has system clipboard support built in. You can check this with the command:

```
echo has('clipboard')
```

Or simply by inspecting the output of:

```
:version
```

Comment: trying this out .. hold on

Comment: `has(clipboard)` returns 0 ;(   So looks like I should reinstall `vim.` Thx for the heads up.

Comment: Update: I installed `gnome-vim` which returns `1` for `has('clipboard')`  and saw 'yanked 7 lines` but still *nothing* in clipboard.

Comment: @javadba How are you checking? `clipboard=unnamed` will mean yanked text goes into the "PRIMARY selection". Possibly you want `clipboard=unnamedplus` instead?

Comment: tried the `clipboard=unnamedplus`: also does not work. I am running this in `docker`: and it appears the problem were a general one with the `clipboard` sharing with a `macos` host: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703070/docker-container-sharing-clipboard-with-host